# android php - posting bytes array to php and retrive data correctly

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to send a byte array from java using loopj asynchttp. but at the server I get different value. what is correct why of POSTing bytes array to php and converting it in php? I also tried base64 with no luck.

```
byte[] mydata = {};

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("t1", mydata);

    client.post("http://example.com/get.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    ..........
```

server side:

```
    $mydata = $_POST['t1'];
```

Comment: You should receive it on server by using key `t1`

Comment: `$mydata = $_POST['t1'];`

Comment: it is a miss type in example I posted here.